# error in running a simple C code in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I wrote a simple C code for displaying a matrix in visual studio but it gives the following errors:

**-Error    1** error C2085: 'main' : not in formal parameter list

**-Error    2** error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'

**-Error    3** error C2084: function 'void print_matrix(float (*)[3])'

as I'm new in C language I don't know where is the problem and how to cope with it.
Thanks for any help

here is the written code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_matrix (float a [3][3])

void main(void)
{
    float p [3][3] = { {1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 1.0, 0.0}, {0.0, 0.0, 1.0} };
printf("\nMatrix 1:\n");
print_matrix(p);
}

void print_matrix(float a [3][3])
{
    int ii,jj;
        for (ii=0;ii<3;ii++){
            for (jj=0;jj<3;jj++){
                printf("%f\t",a[ii][jj]);
    }
            printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all there is a semi-colon missing after the first declaration of `print_matrix`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot a semicolon `;` after your function declaration. Moreover the prototype of `main` is `int main(void)` or `int main(int, char **)`, not `void main(void)`.

Comment: thank you for your answers, but I saw void main(void) in one of the training movies for visual studio and incredibly it worked correctly! so why it doesn't work here?

Comment: The standard says that there are just two correct prototypes of `main` function. It compiles maybe with you, but with an other compiler/computer this may fail.

Comment: you're right.I got it, Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Here's one problem

```
void print_matrix (float a [3][3])               
                                  ^
```

needs a semicolon:

```
void print_matrix (float a [3][3]);
                                  ^
```

Your function header for `main` is missing the return type, `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Missing `;` on the second line of text, i.e. the `print_matrix` line.  I.e. you want it to be:

```
void print_matrix (float a [3][3]);
```